# Variable cronjob frequency

Tags: cron

I wish to backup mysql and have a script which I run daily via cronjob. We have a spiked-peak ordering season in October - is it possible for the same cronjob to be set to run hourly during that month or do I need a second cronjob which I enable/disable for October?

Comment: You can create a second hourly cronjob that just runs in October.

Comment: How would I setup a cronjob to only run during October?  Do I have to enable/disable it in October or do I run it throughout the year but put a clause in the script that it runs to exit if not October?

Comment: The fourth field of the crontab syntax is the month: https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 0):

Hello please use below cron it will run in October everyday everyhour

```
0 * * 10 *
```

You don't need enabled disable it it will run only In October month.
If you want to enable disable it so you can do it by commenting this cron by putting # in front of this line.